# Implementing my own array from a template class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been trying to implement an array class in C++ and have been trying to implement a doesContain method that checks to see if a particular item is in the array or not. I was wondering if something like this would work or would even be a good way of doing it:

```
    T *array;
    int size;

    public:
    array(int length=50) {
        size=length;
        array= new T[length];
    }

    bool doesContain(const T &obj) {
        bool bFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (obj == array[i]) {
                bFlag = true;
             }
        }
        return bFlag;
     }
```

Comment: You could just use `return std::find(array, array + size, obj) != (array + size);` instead of writing a loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Its for an assignment and I am not allowed to use the standard library.

Comment: can't resist: you know nothing, jon snow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have a method that checks if an object is in the array, yes this will work. Provided the operator== is acceptable of course.

I recommend just doing a "return true" when you find a match, and a "return false" at the bottom.

```
bool doesContain(const T &obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (obj == array[i]) {
            return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Good solution.  Some programmers (such as the Linux kernel devs) prefer to set toReturn and break, because then there's a single exit point they can set as a breakpoint.

Comment: @Lorehead in  modern C++, you use RAII class destructors to do the common cleanup required at the exit point

Comment: They’re writing low-level C, it’s true.